# how to randomly sample from a numpy array of probabilities?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
arr = [.2 , .1, .2, .3, .2 ]
```

Now what I want to do is sample from this array, such that the probability i get a certain index is dependent on the probability at the index. So for example, the probability i get index 3 is `.3`

Anyone know any nifty ways to do this?

Comment: look at the `p` argument in [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do weighted sampling with a discrete probability distribution using `np.random.choice` by providing the sampling distribution as a parameter `p`:

```
import numpy as np

x = [.2 , .1, .2, .3, .2 ]

# sample from `x` 100 times according to `x`
n_samples = 100
samples = np.random.choice(x, n_samples, p=x)
```